# Is there a name for exp(-log loss) as an evaluation metric?

Tags: machine-learning

Log loss is a useful evaluation metric in ML classification tasks, but is somewhat hard to grasp. Interestingly, exp(-log loss), i.e. geometric mean of probabilities assigned to the right classes seems to be easier to interpret. Is there a standard name for exp(-log loss) in the context of ML evaluation?

The context is that I'm writing an evaluator for classification problems (i.e. I'm implementing the stuff similar to [what was done in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics)) and I thought it would be nice to add exp(-log loss) as a metric slightly easier to interpret than log-loss. The problem is that I'm not sure how to call it.

Comment: It's called likelihood in stats. The loss is thus negative log likelihood (NLL)

Comment: @Maxim thanks for bringing it up, but likelihood is, as far as I know, not normalized by the test size